# How to use ngx-translate on index.html?

Tags: angular, translation, ngx-translate, angular7

How on Earth or elsewhere do you translate on your main index.html file in an Angular 7 project using ngx-translate.  Basically I have an `<app-root></app-root>` that loads the app, but above that on the index is for example `<title>` and a warning for IE browsers.  Maybe I am just being thick, but I can't figure it out.  Everything is fine outside of the index file, I am assuming mainly because everything gets load by the app.component.ts and app.module.ts after.

This might be a bit vague, let me know and I can provide more details, I am assuming it should be a straightforward - you can't or do this.

Comment: I assume the warning for IE is used to warn them that your Angular app doesn't work on IE. Given that Angular doesn't work, and ngx-translate is part of the Angular app, how could you translate the warning using ngx-translate? For the title, see https://angular.io/api/platform-browser/Title

Comment: @JBNizet it states: Sorry, this app should only be used with Chrome or Internet Explorer version 10 or later.

Comment: So my assumption was correct.

Comment: @JBNizet - I am pretty sure Angular does - https://angular.io/guide/browser-support.  It's just that we prefer them to update from an older than 10 IE or safe the world and stop using IE :]

Comment: @JBNizet  I could move the warning out of the index and put it into /app.component.html file, but the question I guess would still remain, which I feel might be it's not possible.

Comment: If you want it to be handled by Angular, then yes, it should be in the angular app, not outside.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the title field, Angular has a built in Title service. You can easily set the title of the index.html file from any component. https://angular.io/guide/set-document-title

There is also a helpful post I've used in the past for dynamically setting page titles from app.component.ts https://toddmotto.com/dynamic-page-titles-angular-2-router-events. The only change needed for Angular 4+ from this article is using the updated rxjs operators.

Second, for IE, you can use the polyfills.ts file and uncomment a few lines to enable IE 10 and 11 support so you may not even need the warning in the first place. If you absolutely need the warning, you can use good ol' fashion JavaScript to adjust that warning for users. This wouldn't be complex because it should be caught on page load and immediately lock down the app and display the message, else ignored and angular loads.

Overall, best practice is to include what you can inside the app.component.html file at the root of your angular project.